# Changing the values of multiple MySQL Primary Keys

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with about 2,600 existing rows, each with its own primary key.

These primary keys have a lot of random values.  I would like to replace them with a new set of numbers starting from zero.  Bear in mind, I want to change the primary key values for *existing* rows.

Can this be done in MySQL?

Comment: What's the point? The numbers will still be essentially random, just different.

Comment: @Barmar, I'm combining tables so I need each row to have unique primary keys.

Comment: Assuming the primary key is already auto_increment, leave out the primary key column when copying from one table to another, and it will assign new values.

Comment: If any of these IDs are referenced in other tables, which is typically the case, you're going to have to go and renumber those, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a [user defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html):

```
set @i := -1; -- one less than the first id value you want
update mytable set
id = (@i := @i + 1)
order by id;
```

The `order by` ensures that keys stay in the same order and prevents ids from colliding mid-update.

See a [live demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab35e/1) in SQLFiddle.

Comment: After dome refkection, I've refined it a bit more by adding the `order by`.

Answer (score 2):

The safe thing to do is to drop the existing column and primary key and to assign a new column.

```
alter table t drop primary key, add newkey int primary key auto_increment;
```

This will add a new auto-incremented primary key.

You can see this at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3b99a/1).